# How can I make iTerm2 hotkey window fill out the whole screen?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, iterm, fullscreen

I am using MacOS Catalina, and I use iTerm as my terminal. My problem is, that every time iTerm has been closed, and opened again, it only opens in half screen. I know I can drag it down to full screen with my cursor, but it's super annoying if I have to do that every time I open it.

Is there a way to make it full screen by default?

Comment: Do you mean macOS fullscreen mode? What do you mean by „drag it down“?

Comment: macOS fullscreen mode, yes. I drag it down instead of clicking the green circle/button in the top left corner because there is no circle/button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, go to preferences under the iTerm menu item. When the panel opens, select the `Profiles` option at the top of the panel. Once that opens, click on the `Hotkey Window` option, and then click the `window` tab near the top right. In that window you can define the window size or on the right select instead of Normal, Full Screen. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jmh, don't forget to say that I need to click on the `Hotkey Window` tab before clicking on the `Windows` tab. Upvoted + accepted!

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have to press anything.  I changed from Normal to Full Screen and restarted iTerm.  The window opened in full screen without doing anything else. I'll look into this but don't want to add it until I'm sure it's needed,  Thanks again.

Comment: oh i miss understood your comment.  i don't know how to make this doable using hotkey.  I was just answering when you asked to make full screen the default.  I'm sorry.

Comment: It's ok, I figured it out. It's the same, but I just have to press that hotkey window before doing the rest.

Comment: well, thanks. I'm glad you got things set!

Comment: I had to restart iterm2 to have any changes on window style to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the profile for the hotkey window to always fill the whole screen with the drop-down menu `iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > NAME OF HOTKEY PROFILE > Window > Style`.

[image: screenshot of the aforementioned drop-down menu]

Alternatively, if you want to toggle between a half-screen and full-screen hotkey window, the menu item `Window > Zoom` achieves something to this effect, as long as the `Style` is set to something like `Full-Width Top of Screen`.

[image]

When you open the hotkey window, the menu bar does not automatically switch to iTerm2, but you can still use the shortcut (which is ⇧⌘0 on my system; it might be different on yours).